# Writing output of command to file or variable always writes 0

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to write a script such that when I call it, it executes one set of commands if the bash shell is 10 seconds old, and another if it is more than that. My attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i content=$(ps -o etimes= -p "$BASHPID")
if  (( content > 10 ))
then
        echo "true" #test
        command1
else
        echo "false" #test
        command2
        command3
fi
```

However, the output is always false. Then I tried,

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -o etimes= -p "$$" > file
read -d $'\x04' sec < "$file"
if (( sec > 10 ))
then
        echo "true" #test
        command1
else
        echo "false" #test
        command2
        command3
fi
```

Upon checking what was stored in `file`, I realised no matter when I called the script, the output written to the file was always 0. How to fix this so that `ps` always give time since the current bash shell process was launched? This output must also be writable to a variable or file.

Ran a script with a command output, which changes over time, read to a variable. Output does not change over time and instead remains 0. Tried writing to a file instead, did not fix issue.

Comment: If you run a script normally, it creates a subprocess (running bash or whatever) to execute the script. That subprocess will have been running for 0 seconds (when it starts), so checking `$$` will tell you that. Even worse, `$( )` creates a subshell, so using `$BASHPID` inside that will get you info about the subshell, not the main shell process. If you want info about the shell *that the script was run from*, you need to get its PID and then get info about that process.

Comment: pretty sure that $BASHPID does not change in subshell while $$ does. I may have that reversed. -- testing, yes I have that reversed: $$ does not change in a subshell but BASHPID does

Comment: $PPID gets the shell's parent process id.

Comment: which *`bash shell is 10 seconds old`* are you referring to? there's the `bash` shell at the command prompt, another `bash` shell is invoked when you execute the script, another `bash` shell is invoked for each `$(<command>)` construct

Comment: @markp-fuso The one which is the parent shell. I want to get the "age" from ps of the bash shell which I get by clicking on the terminal icon or a new terminal tab. Basically the bash shell at the command prompt, not the ones which are invoked at script execution nor the ones from the $(<command>) constructs.

Comment: @GordonDavisson and @glenn jackman Thank you! I finally understand why it didn't work. So, either I need to reference the `$PPID` inside the script or, run a command writing the `$BASHPID` to a file outside of the script. Also why does, `alias refresh='ps -o etimes= -p "$$" > file && ./script.sh'` not work? I have tried this multiple times and has the same error as before when I try reading from `file` in `script.sh`.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I got it to work.
`#!/bin/bash
# ~/.bashrc
alias refresh='ps -o etimes= -p "$$" > file && ./script.sh'`

`#!/bin/bash
read -rd '' content <file || :
if  (( content > 10 ))
then
        echo "true"
        echo $content
        exec bash

else
        echo "false"
        echo $content
        archey3
        exec bash`

When I run `refresh` it correctly displays the "age" and then when I run again, it again grabs the correct time again from the new bash shell launched through the script. Again, Thanks for the help everyone.